# Laravel validation rule for value based on a table, but can be zero

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.7

How can I create a validation rule to a value what can be `0` but if not, then must be based on an existing value of a table?

Is there a built-in solution or any best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would go with a nullable field instead of having 0, and then the validation will be:

```
'field' => 'nullable|exists:table,column'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use

```
'field' => 'sometimes|exists:table,column'
```